# "Deployed" stabilizer fins: installed in dock or unfolded at sea?

Tags: word-meaning

I have the [following passage](http://evolution.skf.com/taking-the-plunge/):

> When rough waters hit a cruise ship, the vessel stays surprisingly level. Its secret is [stabilizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_(ship)), relatively small movable fins attached to the hull below the water line. These small components have a huge effect on ship performance; they are capable of reducing roll by more than 85 percent. Shaped like aeroplane wings, these fins are **deployed** from the side of the hull and pivot up or down to exert dive or lift, thereby counteracting the waves’ effect on the ship.

What do you think is the meaning of **deploy** here: are the fins installed in a dock ("deployed" permanently) or are they unfolded as needed when (the?) weather turns rough?

Comment: It is the 'unfolded' meaning in use here - the fins are attached to the ship (either in the hull or folded against the hull) and are _unfolded/deployed_ when needed. _Deploy_ is a bit of an oddity - it's not very popular until the 18th Century and after that it's used mostly as a military term _deploying troops_ etc. Usage seems to have picked up dramatically in the last half century. See also defn.2 here http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deploy [Ocford Dictionaries] "Bring into effective action".

Comment: Thanks, Frank! Couldn't *deploy* be used as *pre-installed* at all? I just thought that maybe it is used in the text as a fancy alternative to "installed". Because many ships have these fins fixed permanently, as I understand.

Comment: I think that might be where _deploy_ is getting a lot of it's recent usage from; installation of software but I found no well known dictionary definitions to back that up as a documented meaning (didn't look too hard though). If it was meant as _installed_ I think it would say _...these fins are deployed **on** the side of the hull..._ rather than _from_.

Comment: Oh, "on vs. from", a nice observation, Frank! Thanks again!

Comment: I think it simply means "put to use". I'm rather sure I've seen and heard it used in movies and novels, very often in those ones that are aviation-related. (Something like "Flaps deployed." or "Slats deployed.") I'm not sure about these fins, but I think it's quite similar.

Comment: So the cruise ship sailed for months with only one stabilizer fin? That's rhetorical--mostly.

Comment: As for the question, another hint is that it is already stated that the fins are attached to the hull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Inline with this [meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1119/6494)  by [snailboat](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/230/) I've added this answer to summarise the comments I left (when I should have left an answer).</sup>

Deploy is a bit of an oddity - it's not very popular until the 18th Century and after that it's used mostly as a military term: "deploying troops" etc., but usage seems to have picked up dramatically in the last half century.

OED1 has a (15th century) meaning that is marked as obsolete of

> *trans.* To unfold, display.

A number of dictionaries including Oxford Dictionaries<sup>[here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deploy)</sup> have a definition as

> "Bring into effective action".

It appears to be both the 'unfolded' meaning in use here - *the fins are attached to the ship (either in the hull or folded against the hull)* and also the 'bring into action' meaning - *and are unfolded/deployed when needed* .

The 'bring into action' meaning is mentioned by [Damkerng T](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3281/). in a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34170/deployed-stabilizer-fins-installed-in-dock-or-unfolded-at-sea#comment64126_34170)

> I think it simply means "put to use". I'm rather sure I've seen and heard it used in movies and novels, very often in those ones that are aviation-related. (Something like "Flaps deployed." or "Slats deployed.") I'm not sure about these fins, but I think it's quite similar.

I agree that that usage is quite common; *flaps deployed*, *shields deployed*, *weapons deployed* etc.

---

> Question : *Couldn't deploy be used as pre-installed at all*

I think that might be where deploy is getting a lot of it's recent usage from; installation of software but I found no well known dictionary definitions to back that up as a documented meaning (didn't look too hard though).

If *deploy* was intended to mean *installed* I think it would say ...*these fins are deployed **on** the side of the hull*... rather than ***from***.